# Responsive padding flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im trying to pass a percentage of screen size to padding widget but it says the value should be constant, also when you just type numbers it shows different UIs in different devices.
so what should we do for responsive padding.

```
double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(h*0.2, 5.0, 50.0, 0.0),
        child:...)
```

Comment: Just remove the "const" that is in front of "EdgeInsets..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `const` keyword from your `EdgeInsets`. The `const` keyword means that Flutter knows the values that the specific widget will use beforehand. Obviously, if those values depend on the height of the device, Flutter is not able to know them until it executes your code.

Also, consider using [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) instead of `MediaQuery` to get the available space constraints. In my experience, it is easier and more flexible to build the desired responsive layouts by obtaining a reference to the available screen space, instead of using the fixed device size.